# malloc a complex<float> in C++ and CUDA

Tags: c++, malloc, cuda

In C++, if I want an array of complex I might do something like this:

```
complex<float> *temp = new complex<float>[size];
```

Can I change this into a malloc statement?

What about if I want to use cudaMalloc to give me an array on the GPU of complex floats?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Can I change this into a malloc statement?

No, but you can change it into a malloc statement with Placement-New. Can't see why you'd want to do that though.

> What about if I want to use cudaMalloc to give me an array on the GPU of complex floats?

Again, you'll have to use placement new.

Answer (score 1):

For Cuda there is the type cuComplex for complex floa values and cuDoubleComplex for double complex values.
You can use both in combination with cudaMalloc or cublasAlloc.

Comment: I guess if I have already populated an array with complex<float> I have to loop over those values to set the values in an array of cuComplex?

Comment: cuComplex should be a typedef for the C99 complex.h as long as your platform supports complex.h, otherwise its a typedef for float2.  so its not possible to directly convert c++ complex to c99 complex, but there are some helper functions for dealing with cuComplex in CUDA

Answer (score 0):

Unless `complex` has no constructor, no.  You should use `new` when allocating arrays in C++.

Comment: Not true. Complex would need to be a POD type, not just have no user-defined constructor.

Comment: From wiki: A POD type in C++ is defined as either a scalar type or a POD class. A POD class has no user-defined copy assignment operator, no user-defined destructor, and no non-static data members that are not themselves PODs. Moreover, a POD class must be an aggregate, meaning it has no user-declared constructors, no private nor protected non-static data, no bases and no virtual functions.